# Memory leak in rendering pdf page

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, ios5

Hello i am struggling at finding memory leaks. I and stuck at one :) 
I got memory leak in this method:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CATiledLayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
#ifdef DEBUGX
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
#endif

    CGPDFPageRef drawPDFPageRef = NULL;

    CGPDFDocumentRef drawPDFDocRef = NULL;

    @synchronized(self) // Block any other threads
    {
        drawPDFDocRef = CGPDFDocumentRetain(_PDFDocRef);

        drawPDFPageRef = CGPDFPageRetain(_PDFPageRef);
    }

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // White

    CGContextFillRect(context, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(context)); // Fill

    if (drawPDFPageRef != NULL) // Go ahead and render the PDF page into the context
    {
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, self.bounds.size.height); CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);

        CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(drawPDFPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox, self.bounds, 0, true));

        CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault); CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationDefault);

        CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, drawPDFPageRef); // 100 %
    }

    CGPDFPageRelease(drawPDFPageRef); CGPDFDocumentRelease(drawPDFDocRef); 
}
```

I can't figure out what is wrong ? Maybe someone could help me on this ?

edited:
leak:

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
Malloc 8 Bytes,1    0x46b608    8 Bytes CoreGraphics    mem_alloc
```